# Create a Table With Merged TH Cells

Tags: php

I am creating an Excel download code, in which I am merging the TH cells and looping through TR to put data under specific merged TH.

But all of data is reflecting on first TH row. Below is code:

```
            $K=0;
        while($ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc() )
                {

                    if($ROW['type'] == $_GET['separate_id'])
                {
                    $DATE[] = $ROW['end_time'];
                    $meta_values[] = $ROW['meta_values'];

                    $body             = '


<table style="border:1px solid #000; border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead style="border:1px solid #000; padding:8px;width:150px; height:25px;font-size:15px">
';
foreach($DATE as $DATES)
{
        $DATESVIEW = explode('T',$DATES);
        $body .=' <th colspan="2">'.$DATESVIEW[0].'</th> ';
}

$body             .= '
</thead>



';
                foreach($meta_values as $VALS)
                {

                    $META_VALS = explode(' | ',$VALS);
                    foreach($META_VALS as $VALUEs)
                    {
                        $REs = explode(' - ', $VALUEs);
                    $body             .= '

  <tbody>
<tr style="border:1px solid #000; padding:8px;width:150px; height:25px;font-       size:15px">
            <td style="border:1px solid #000; padding:8px; width:150px; height:25px;font-size:15px">'.$REs[0].'</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #000; padding:8px; width:150px; height:25px;font-size:15px">'.$REs[1].'</td>

</tr>
 </tbody>
';
                    }
                    }



                }
                   $K++;
                    }
                $body             .= '


  </table>

';
```

Comment: Your table head does not contain any row, only cells.

Comment: theres a <thead>and <th>

Comment: Exactly, and the `<tr>` is missing...

Comment: You still need to wrap your `<th>`'s in `<tr>...</tr>`

Comment: See here for simple examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Examples